# Vue testing with jest: $route is always undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I've tried a lot of things but $route seems to always be undefined and I have this error on shallowMount: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`.

In my component, I want to check the params of the $route but it is always undefined. I've looked the documentation and mocked the `$route` to set it but it seems like the $route is not mocked. I've also tried using localVue.use(VueRouter), thinking that it would set $route but it didn't. Does anyone have an idea why the following doesn't work in both cases?

my-component.ts

```
@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  get organisationId() {
    return this.$route.params.organisationId;
  }
}
```

I've tried the 2 following tests with the solutions I've talked about:

my-component.spec.ts

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';
import router from '@/router';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let cmp: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    cmp  = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      router,
      mocks: {
        $route: {
          params: {
            id: 'id'
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });

  it('Should render a Vue instance', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(cmp.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

my-component.spec.ts

```
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let cmp: any;
  localVue.use(VueRouter);
  const router = new VueRouter();

  beforeEach(() => {
    cmp  = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      router
    });
  });

  it('Should render a Vue instance', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    expect(cmp.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I found the problem! In my component, I use a directive but I forgot to use it in my `localVue` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm answering my question 2 years later but I thought it could help people with the same issue so here is how I've fixed it:

In my component, I used a directive but I forgot to use it in my localVue instance. The error didn't lead me to that at all. When you use a directive in your component, you should add

```
import directive from '@/directives/my-directive';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.directive('myDirective', directive);
```

Answer (score 3):

You were mocking `$route` right in #1 test. You can access `$route` property of test component via `wrapper.vm.$route` (or `cmp.vm.$route` in your case). And There is example:

```
import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

let wrapper: Wrapper<MyComponent>

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      mocks: {
        $route: {
          params: {
            id: 'id'
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })

  it('$route has passed params', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$route.params.id).toBe('id')
  })
})
```

Comment: Sadly, I still had the error mocking $route and I don't really understand why

Comment: Strange.. Hope you have noticed that I am neither importing ```router``` object nor creating new instance of ```VueRouter``` in the test.

Comment: Yes, I did the same but I found the problem ! In my component, I use a directive but I forgot to use it in my localVue instance. The error didn't lead me to that at all but I finally solved it ! Thanks for your help Eduardo